# How to develop an Android App that can run on Chrome OS?

Tags: android, google-chrome-os, google-chrome-arc

Recently, Google released some Android apps that can run on Chrome OS. How can I develop apps that will do the same?

- Is a specific SDK different from phone, tv, glass necessary?
- Does the source code of an existing Android app need to change?
- Do any extra libraries need to be imported into my project?

Or can an existing app run on Chrome OS without any changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [announcement for ARC](http://chrome.blogspot.com/2014/09/first-set-of-android-apps-coming-to.html) in September of 2014 said:

> - Duolingo - a fun and free way to learn a new language before your next trip
> - Evernote - write, collect and find what matters to you, with a full-size keyboard and touchscreen
> - Sight Words - a delightful way for you to help improve your child's reading skills
> - Vine - create short, beautiful, looping videos in a simple and fun way
>
> These first apps are the result of a project called the App Runtime
>   for Chrome (Beta), which we announced earlier this summer at Google
>   I/O. Over the coming months, we’ll be working with a select group of
>   Android developers to add more of your favorite apps so you’ll have a
>   more seamless experience across your Android phone and Chromebook.

In April of 2015, Google released the preview of ARC. You can find more information on [the ARC website](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the new [developer preview documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc) to get started.  ARC is still in beta so may be rough around the edges, but it is now open for all developers to try their apps.  From the doc:

> To test your app, you need three things:
>
> - Your APK.
> - PC, Mac, Linux, or Chromebook on Chrome Version 41+.
> - The [ARC Welder app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Brian ok, added the basic info for what to do (though the app download is also a link, no real way around that)